# How to subset multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have split data and metadata into separate dataframes for convenience. I would like to subset both at the same time, so I don't have to repeat myself. My example attempt below is a mess of if statements. This because .loc[], .iloc[], and whether to leave all columns in a certain dimension (:) are ""part of the syntax"" (for lack of better explanation), and thus not passable as regular function arguments.

There has to be a better way! I must either be missing something obvious, or trying to do something which is really dumb for some reason that goes over my head.

I am aware that there are workarounds, and about the xy problem problem, so advice on any level on how to handle this is welcome.

How do I do this, or why should I not even try to do this?

```
# Make some example data
all_data = pd.DataFrame(
    data = np.array(range(9)).reshape(3, 3), 
    columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(all_data)
#    a  b  c
# 0  0  1  2
# 1  3  4  5
# 2  6  7  8
import string
all_metadata = pd.DataFrame(
    data = np.array(list(string.ascii_lowercase))[:6].reshape(3, 2),
    columns = ['meta1', 'meta2'])
print(all_metadata)
#   meta1 meta2
# 0     a     b
# 1     c     d
# 2     e     f

# Subset both (several) dataframes in a single call
def subset_dataframes(
        dataframes,
        rows = None,
        cols = None,
        indexer = 'loc'):
    dfs_out = []
    for dataframe in dataframes:
        if rows is not None and cols is not None:
            if indexer == 'loc':
                df = dataframe.loc[rows, cols]
            elif indexer == 'iloc':
                df = dataframe.iloc[rows, cols]
        elif rows is not None:
            if indexer == 'loc':
                df = dataframe.loc[rows, :]
            elif indexer == 'iloc':
                df = dataframe.iloc[rows, :]
        elif cols is not None:
            if indexer == 'loc':
                df = dataframe.loc[:, cols]
            elif indexer == 'iloc':
                df = dataframe.iloc[:, cols]
        dfs_out.append(df)
    return(dfs_out)

subset_dataframes(
    dataframes = (all_data, all_metadata), 
    rows = all_metadata.meta1.isin(['a', 'c'])
    )
# [   a  b  c
#  0  0  1  2
#  1  3  4  5,
#    meta1 meta2
#  0     a     b
#  1     c     d]

# Works, but an absolute mess of code
```

Comment: Can you add one or two examples of what you'd like to do in "long form"? It's not entirely clear to me what kind of repetition you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:` (when used in a lookup) is just a shorthand for `slice(None, None, None)` which can be further shortened to just `slice(None)` (thanks @fsimonjetz). So you
can completely skip using a default value of `None` for your `rows` and `cols` and just use an
empty slice. Then you don’t need to perform any checks:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string

all_data = pd.DataFrame(
    data = np.array(range(9)).reshape(3, 3),
    columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
)
all_metadata = pd.DataFrame(
    data = np.array(list(string.ascii_lowercase))[:6].reshape(3, 2),
    columns = ['meta1', 'meta2']
)

def subset_dataframes(dfs, rows=slice(None), cols=slice(None), indexer='loc'):
    dfs_out = []
    for dataframe in dfs:
        if indexer == 'loc':
            df = dataframe.loc[rows, cols]
        elif indexer == 'iloc':
            df = dataframe.iloc[rows, cols]
        dfs_out.append(df)
    return dfs_out


res = subset_dataframes(
    [all_data, all_metadata], rows=all_metadata.meta1.isin(['a', 'c'])
)
print(*res, sep='\n'*2)
   # a  b  c
# 0  0  1  2
# 1  3  4  5

  # meta1 meta2
# 0     a     b
# 1     c     d
```

However, in my opinion this is a lot of song-and-dance for what boils down to a
one line using comprehension syntax.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string

all_data = pd.DataFrame(
    data = np.array(range(9)).reshape(3, 3),
    columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
)
all_metadata = pd.DataFrame(
    data = np.array(list(string.ascii_lowercase))[:6].reshape(3, 2),
    columns = ['meta1', 'meta2']
)

rows = all_metadata['meta1'].isin(['a', 'c'])
res = [ # do you need a function for a single line list comprehension?
    df.loc[rows, :] for df in [all_data, all_metadata]
]
print(*res, sep='\n\n')
   # a  b  c
# 0  0  1  2
# 1  3  4  5

  # meta1 meta2
# 0     a     b
# 1     c     d
```

---

As pointed out by @fsimonjetz, you can further shorten the first approach using the following code. Even with this adjustment, I would say that this shouldn't be a function and can be a simple list-comprehension.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string

all_data = pd.DataFrame(
    data = np.array(range(9)).reshape(3, 3),
    columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
)
all_metadata = pd.DataFrame(
    data = np.array(list(string.ascii_lowercase))[:6].reshape(3, 2),
    columns = ['meta1', 'meta2']
)

def subset_dataframes(dfs, rows=slice(None), cols=slice(None), indexer='loc'):
    return [getattr(d, indexer)[rows, cols] for d in dfs]

res = subset_dataframes(
    [all_data, all_metadata], 
    rows=all_metadata.meta1.isin(['a', 'c'])
)

print(*res, sep='\n'*2)
   # a  b  c
# 0  0  1  2
# 1  3  4  5

  # meta1 meta2
# 0     a     b
# 1     c     d
```

Comment: There is also `slice(None)` which is a shorthand for `slice(None, None, None)`, and with `getattr` we can parameterize the indexer directly, e.g., `getattr(dataframe, indexer)[rows, cols]`. That would make it a one-liner with a list comprehension.

Comment: updated to add in these adjustments. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Thanks for including it! I fully agree it doesn't seem worth the effort, seeing how the readability of the code suffers, too.

Comment: Wonderful answer! You answered both how to do it and why I shouldn't do it perfectly I think. I also learnt something about both `slice` and `getattr` in the process. I fully agree that list comprehension is much preferred. Thank you both!

Comment: I guess the reason a function is a bad idea is that I was planning to feed it only one set of rows and cols per call anyways, which removes any reason to make a function that generalises over different indexing cases. The only remaining "benefit" would be saving a minimal amount of list comprehension syntax on repetitive use. This at the cost of massively sacrificing clarity.

Answer (score -1):

You can define the subset conditions separately and then applying them to each dataframe in a more concise manner.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

# Make some example data
all_data = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.array(range(9)).reshape(3, 3),
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(all_data)

import string
all_metadata = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.array(list(string.ascii_lowercase))[:6].reshape(3, 2),
    columns=['meta1', 'meta2'])
print(all_metadata)


# Subset both dataframes in a single call
def subset_dataframes(dataframes, rows=None, cols=None, indexer='loc'):
    dfs_out = []
    for dataframe in dataframes:
        if indexer == 'loc':
            df = dataframe.loc[rows, cols]
        elif indexer == 'iloc':
            df = dataframe.iloc[rows, cols]
        dfs_out.append(df)
    return dfs_out


# Define subset conditions separately
rows_condition = all_metadata.meta1.isin(['a', 'c'])
cols_condition = None  # You can define this as well if needed

# Call the function with the defined conditions
result = subset_dataframes(
    dataframes=(all_data, all_metadata),
    rows=rows_condition,
    cols=cols_condition
)
print(result)
```

Comment: Did you try running this before posting? The code fails with KeyError: None. This since you cannot index a dataframe with None, like `df = dataframe.loc[rows, None]` for example.

Comment: Also see the accepted answer. It solves the question well